# Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields text_url field prepending http://

Tags: metabox, sanitization

I'm using the [Custom Metaboxes and Fields](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) code wich is pretty good. However I need sanitization on URL fields of course but the built in text_url field type is adding 'http://' to my entries.

I know it is using WP's [esc_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) (cmb_Meta_box_types.php)
And cmb_Meta_box_Sanitize [esc_url_raw()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url_raw)

How can I get this field type to return only the inputted value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that esc URL was the culprit. Even though I wanted to hard code the base URL

eg. http://facebook.com/

I was esc_url'ing the input field for which to append to the base. I've switched to using a regular text field and am esc_url'ing the entire output string.